# Java - JPA always append to query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a mapped superclass that all entities are expected to extend:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPersistedEntity {

  /** The id. */
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  /** The delete. */
  @Column(name = "DELETE_IND", nullable = false)
  private Boolean delete;

  /** The uuid. */
  @Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false)
  private String uuid;

  /** The created time stamp. */
  @Column(name = "CREATED_TS", nullable = false)
  private Long createdTs;

  /** The modified time stamp. */
  @Column(name = "MODIFIED_TS", nullable = false)
  private Long modifiedTs;

/* methods omitted for brevity */
}
```

There is delete indicator (delete) that is set to true when it is okay to delete the persisted entity - otherwise, the entity is just marked for deletion.

What I am unsure of is how to always append the needed value of delete to every query without having to do so for every query. I'm actually not sure if this is even possible. The searches I've performed point to actually defining every query to look for the value of delete.

Can someone, at the very least, provide me with alternate ways of searching for the answer (happy to self-serve) -or- offer a possible way to append a parameter to every query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation:

> Where clause to add to the element Entity or target entity of a
>   collection. The clause is written in SQL. A common use case here is
>   for soft-deletes.

So in your example it would look like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Where(clause = "DELETE_IND = 0")
public abstract class AbstractPersistedEntity {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's working for me. Marking answer according.